# filter a request in django serializer with the current logged-in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Help please,

So, I am making a request with a serializer and what I need is to filter the response by current logged-in user. I was thinking about doing the request using serializerMethodField but it's a read-only type so I could not do anything with it after. Specially this code line which is necessary for my form, because it will retrieve all wallet linked to the current user into a select field, won't work :

`to = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_wallets'))`

I thought also about the way of castrate the return type that I will get from get_user_wallets method into something that I can use as a queryset. But it seems not easy to do it. Maybe someone has a better approach of doing what I want.

Bellow is the code :

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    to = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_wallets'))

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['amount', 'to']

    def get_user_wallets(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request:
            wallet = Wallet.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.pk)
            return wallet
```

Thank you for your answers and suggestions.

My model is this one

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    wallet_id = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_type_id = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    to = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="send_to", verbose_name='Send to')
    description = models.TextField()
    amount = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: why don't you filter the queryset in your view? can you include your models please?

Comment: I have just added my model. But, I don't know if it possible to filter in views and my form will show data like the one I will filter in views. But if you know how to do it, it will help also.